# How to filter an array of complex object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array of users and each user has a array of tags
and I have an array of selected Tags
What is the best way in ES6 to filter the users by selected tags

```
const users = [
  {
    username: "john",
    tags: [{id:1}, {id:3},{id:5},{id:7}]
  },
  {
    username: "becky",
    tags: [{id:1}, {id:7},{id:6}]
  },
  {
    username: "susy",
    tags: [{id:1}, {id:4},{id:5}]
  },
  {
    username: "tyson",
    tags: [{id:3},{id:5}]
  },
];
```

and my selected tags are

```
let tagIds = [7,5];
```

and I expect to receive a result as

```
users = [
  {
    username: "john",
    tags: [{id:1}, {id:3},{id:5},{id:7}]
  },
];
```

Comment: You can use [`array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: but how to implement that

Comment: Ideally your tags would be `[1,3,5,7]` rather than `[{id:1},{id:3},{id:5},{id:7}]`.

Comment: Hi jarmod I simplified the object for this question, the tag in the users has other properties like name category too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter the users, and then check that every `id` is found in the tags of the user by using `Array.some()`:

```js
const users = [{"username":"john","tags":[{"id":1},{"id":3},{"id":5},{"id":7}]},{"username":"becky","tags":[{"id":1},{"id":7},{"id":6}]},{"username":"susy","tags":[{"id":1},{"id":4},{"id":5}]},{"username":"tyson","tags":[{"id":3},{"id":5}]}];

const tagIds = [7,5];

const result = users.filter(({ tags }) => 
  tagIds.every(id => 
    tags.some(t => t.id === id)
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you Ori that is exactly what I wanted

Comment: Hi Ori I am new in this platform and I am just wondering why am I receiving downvoting for this question is it something wrong I did?

Comment: You usually get downvotes for not showing your attempt, even if it's partial, not working, etc... In addition, you might get downvotes if this a canonic question, which was asked and answered a lot of times (duplicate), and because sometimes it's just "people". I suggest reading the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article, and don't take the downvotes to seriously.